# How to strip whitespace from before but not after punctuation in python

Tags: python, regex

relative python newbie here.  I have a text string output from a program I can't modify. For discussion lets say:

```
text = "This text . Is to test . How it works ! Will it! Or won't it ? Hmm ?"
```

I want to remove the space before the punctuation, but not remove the second space.  I've been trying to do it with regex, and I know that I can match the instances I want using 
match='\s[\?.!\"]\s' as my search term.

```
x=re.search('\s[\?\.\!\"]\s',text)
```

Is there a way with a re.sub to replace the search term with the leading whitespace removed? Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses everyone.  It felt like I was close, but I was flailing a bit.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Put a group around the text you want to *keep* and refer to that group by number in the replacement pattern:

```
re.sub(r'\s([?.!"](?:\s|$))', r'\1', text)
```

Note that I used a `r''` raw string to avoid having to use too many backslashes; you didn't need to add quite so many, however.

I also adjusted the match for the following space; it now matches either a space or the end of the string.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "This text . Is to test . How it works ! Will it! Or won't it ? Hmm ?"
>>> re.sub(r'\s([?.!"](?:\s|$))', r'\1', text)
"This text. Is to test. How it works! Will it! Or won't it? Hmm?"
```

Comment: The explanation on the grouping was very helpful - for some reason that wasn't sinking in previously.

Comment: +1 nice answer. In my case I need your solution to work for apostrophes also? `that 's what I 'm talking about` should become `that's what I'm talking about` Any idea, suggestion? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Antoine: that's not stripping, that's a replacement inside the string. Use a regular expression there. Off the cuff, untested: `re.sub(r"\b\s+'\b", r"'", yourstring)`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters it works! Many thanks for the very prompt help!

Answer (score 5):

Use [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) instead of [`re.search`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search).

```
>>> text = "This text . Is to test . How it works ! Will it! Or won't it ? Hmm ?"
>>> re.sub(r'\s+([?.!"])', r'\1', text)
"This text. Is to test. How it works! Will it! Or won't it? Hmm?"
```

You don't need to escape `?`, `.`, `!`, `"` inside `[]` becaue special characters lose their meaning inside `[]`.

Comment: Sure. And he probably doesn't want " to have whitespace removed before it, as in this sentence: Sally said, "Hello, world!"   As it would be changed to: Sally said,"Hello, world!"