# Regex for removing whitespace after a parenthesis python

Tags: python, regex

I have strings such as the following:

```
s1 = 'Hello , this is a [ test ] string with ( parenthesis ) .'
```

I am trying to remove whitespace surrounding punctuation so it should look like this:

```
s1 = 'Hello, this is a [test] string with (parenthesis).'
```

I found this to bit of code from  here: [How to strip whitespace from before but not after punctuation in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18878936/how-to-strip-whitespace-from-before-but-not-after-punctuation-in-python)

```
req = re.sub(r'\s([?,.!"](?:\s|$))', r'\1', text)
```

I added ] and ) to the regex to include removing whitespace after ] or )

```
 req = re.sub(r'\s([?,.!\])"](?:\s|$))', r'\1', text)
```

So it now looks like this:

```
s1 = 'Hello, this is a [ test] string with ( parenthesis).'
```

Now I have been trying to adjust this to also remove the whitespace before [ or ( but I can't figure out how. I am very confused when it comes it regex.

I understand re.sub() is replacing the second argument (r'\1') with the first argument but I don't understand what (r'\1') actually means.

Any help would be appreciated,

Cheers

Comment: `\1` means the first capturing matched group. A group is what is surrounded by parenthesis in a pattern (in your pattern`([?,.!\])`) you can have non capturing groups by doing `(?:)` (in your pattern `(?:\s|$))`)

Comment: `re.sub(r'([[(])\s+|\s+([])])(?:\s+(?=[^\w\s]))?', r'\1\2', text)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/PwpUJK/1))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help using lookbehind & lookahead.

```
import re

s1 = 'Hello , this is a [ test ] string with ( parenthesis ).'
#print(re.sub(r"(?<=\[|\()(.*?)(?=\)|\])", lambda x: x.group().strip(), s1))
print(re.sub(r'(\s([?,.!"]))|(?<=\[|\()(.*?)(?=\)|\])', lambda x: x.group().strip(), s1))
```

**Output:**

```
Hello, this is a [test] string with (parenthesis).
```

Comment: You are missing the space before the comma.

Comment: @Rakesh thank you very much! I am going to spend some time over the weekend learning about regex now that I can submit my work to my boss

Answer (score 1):

One way is not to capture the space at start and end inside the parenthesis,i.e.

```
 (parens start) some space (capture text) some space (parens close)
      |                          |                         |
   Group 1                   Group 2                    Group 3
```

---

Match the `. or , preceded by space using alternation` and capture it in a separate group

```
([[({])\s*(.*?)\s*([\]\)\}])|\s+([,.])
```

[image]

Replace by `\1\2\3\4`

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/NjT7bx/3/)

Comment: @CodeManiac thank you! I wish I could pick both answers as my accepted one but I will go with the first one to keep it fair, but thank you!

Comment: @codiearcher No problem always happy to help :)