# remove space in punctuation in python

Tags: python

I am trying to remove the white space before the punctuation. Specifically,

```
'I have a dog , I want to walk out . I want to feed my dog . '
```

to

```
'I have a dog, I want to walk out. I want to feed my dog.'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to strip whitespace from before but not after punctuation in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18878936/how-to-strip-whitespace-from-before-but-not-after-punctuation-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Well, first that comes to mind, just replace ' .' with '.'

```
import re
x = 'I have a dog , I want to walk out . I want to feed my dog . '
print(re.sub(r'\s\,', ',', re.sub(r'\s\.','.',x)))
```

final string explained:

```
y = re.sub(r'\s\.','.',x) <- replacing ' .'
z = re.sub(r'\s\,',',',y) <- replacing ' ,'
```

Both action happen sequentially.