# convert column to plain text pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have column like below

df =

```
idx text
0 i
1 am
2 a
3 boy
4 .
5 he
6 is 
7 running
8 
9 .
```

I want to convert it to plain text and remove space before `.` fullstop like below:

```
i am a boy. he is running.
```

I tried but still unsuccessful.

Comment: Show what you tried as properly formatted code in the question.

Comment: What have you tried? What precisely is the issue with the code you tried?

Comment: try `df['text'].str.cat(sep=' ')`

Comment: thank you the above solution also worked without space removal. The below mentioned worked perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need remove one or more spaces before `.` use `.join` with `re.sub`:

```
import re
out = re.sub('\s+\.','.', ' '.join(df['text']))
```

Or:

```
import re
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/18878958/2901002
df = re.sub(r'\s+([.])', r'\1', ' '.join(df['text']))
print (df)
i am a boy. he is running.
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use [`str.cat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html) with specifying the separator, and then replace the extra space with the dot, with just the dot:

```
>>> df['text'].str.cat(sep=' ').replace(' .','.')
Out[30]: 'i am a boy. he is running.'
```